# How to add users to group programatically in cognito using lambda in javascript?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

```
const AWS=require('aws-sdk')
addUserToGroup = () => {
  var params = {
    GroupName: "storeusers" /* required */,
    UserPoolId: "us-west-2_XXXXX" /* required */,
    Username: "joshigarikimukku@gmail.com" /* required 
  */
  }
  var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new 
 AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, 
function (
    err,
    data
  ) {
    if (err) console.log("error...",err, err.stack)
    // an error occurred
    else console.log("data...",data) // successful 
response
  })

}
```

> i am getting this error

error... [CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, 
  if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 
  credError@http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/
  AppEntry.
  bundle? 
  platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:434736:55
 getCredentials@http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/
  AppEntry.bundle? 
  platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:434780:29
 VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS@http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/
  expo/AppEntry.bundle? 
  platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:435172:46
 callListeners@http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/
  AppEntry.bundle? 
  platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:433906:29
 emit@http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/
 AppEntry.bundle  addUserToGroup

commitHookEffectList@http://127.0.0.1:19001/
  node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle? 
  platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:24530:38
  commitPassiveHookEffects@http://127.0.0.1:19001/
   node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?
  callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]

Comment: please help me.

Comment: are you trying to run this function locally?

Comment: yes i am running this locally

Comment: have you assumed a role with the proper lambda permissions locally?

Comment: oh sorry i don't know how to check lambda permissions but i am successfully done authentications by using lambda

Comment: you have to assume a role locally that has permission to invoke lambda.  have you done that?  the aws sdk will read credentials from you aws config file.  those credentials arent present here...